# Margin-left doesn't work properly in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, css, firefox

In my code `margin-left:` is working in two different ways in Firefox and all the other browsers.

On Firefox, the margin is only like 20% of the "real" margin. I tried `@-moz-document url-prefix() { }`, but it didn't solve the issue, it moved both the image that is shown and the "real position from where the cars start moving" to a even bigger margin.

Here's my code:

```
<section id="home" >        
    <div id="home1inner">
        <div id="header">
           *lots of content here*
        </div>
        <img id="cars" src="images/cars.png" />
    </div>  
 </section>
```

```
  #home {   
    position: relative;
    width: calc(100% + 25px);
    overflow-y: scroll;
    background-image: url('images/movie_6.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    height: 690px;
    margin-top: 40px;
}
  #home1inner {
    height: 1550px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}    
  #cars {
    position: absolute;
    height: 690px;
    bottom: -500px;
    margin-left: -300px;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Here's the website itself, where you can check the difference between Firefox and any other browser: http://denea.comeze.com/

Any ideas how to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Firefox, your `cars` ID is defaulting to be centered on the page.

Simply add `left: 0`, like so:

```
#cars {
    position: absolute;
    height: 690px;
    bottom: -500px;
    margin-left: -300px;
    pointer-events: none;
    left: 0;
}
```

and it will start off at the position on the page you want.